# Create a batch script to summarise data from one text file to another text file

Tags: batch-file

A file Datafile.txt, has the following columns and data,

```
SrNo,Store,Vehicle,Type,Qty,Price.
```

Create a batch script to summarise the data into another file summary.txt as follows.

```
Store, Vehicle, Type, Total Value
```

datafile.txt contains the following data

```
SrNo,Store,Vehicle,Type,Qty,Price
1,Northampton,CAR,1,2,10000
2,Northampton,CAR,2,3,15000
3,Northampton,CAR,3,10,20000
4,Northampton,VAN,1,5,25000
5,Northampton,VAN,2,6,30000
```

Please help to create through batch script?

Comment: Sounds interesting!  What does this project pay?  How soon do you need it?  I'm being sarcastic of course.  Questions resembling "Here are my requirements.  Now write it for me" are not appropriate for Stack Overflow.  Show us what you've attempted and maybe we can help you fix your code, rather than supplying you with our code.  But you must demonstrate that you've put forth the effort to solve the problem on your own before asking us for help.  Read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information.

Comment: hi rojo, please see below script I have attempted

Comment: Edit your question to include your code.  [See this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for help formatting code blocks, etc.

Comment: @echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

> "Summary.txt" (
FOR /F "tokens=2,3,4,5,6 delims=," %%A IN (Datafile.txt) DO ( 
        Set /A result = %%D * %%E
        echo %%A,%%B,%%C,!result! 
        
 )
)

Comment: rojo, I don't know how to edit my commandline , please see above my batch script codes. This is working fine all I want to summarise from Qty,price to total value in summary.txt